# JavaFX 11 in Netbeans 10 (with Maven) has no Sources/Javadocs

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans, javadoc

I tried out the [JavaFX tutorial for Netbeans with Maven](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans) and got it running without a problem. Maven found the artifacts, downloaded them, build the project and started it. But I get no code completion (Missing sources and Javadocs).

I tried to download the sources and javadocs for the maven dependencies in Netbeans, but only the sources/javadocs for the wrapper artifacts (e.g. the empty javafx-controls-11) are available. But no sources are found for the actual implementation (e.g. javafx-controls-11-linux).

Where do I find the sources/javadocs and how do I add them to Netbeans?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/44) already filed about this at the OpenJFX docs.

While it hasn't been resolved yet, there is a possible workaround, based on:

> NetBeans only adds javadoc/source jars for a jar with the exact same name and -javadoc/-source suffix

So here are the steps to solve it:

- Install NetBeans [10](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html) and JDK [11.0.2](https://jdk.java.net/11/).
- Clone the HelloFX [sample](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/NetBeans/Non-Modular/Maven) for  NetBeans and Maven, from the OpenJFX samples.
- Update the JavaFX dependencies to 11.0.2.

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.2</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Run it:

  ```
  mvn clean compile exec:java
  ```
- Check that the JavaFX dependencies have been downloaded to your local `m2` repository. Under `<user home>/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2` for instance you will find `javafx-base-11.0.2.jar` and `javafx-base-mac-11.0.2.jar` (or `win`, or `linux` based on your platform).
- Back on NetBeans, right click in the Dependencies folder and select `Download Sources` (see the task progress in the bottom right taskbar), and then `Download Javadoc`(see the task progress).

[image]

- Go to your `m2` repository and verify that there are now `-source` and `-javadoc` jar files.

[image]

However, this won't solve the issue yet, there is an extra step:

- In your `m2` repository, manually rename the `-source` and `-javadoc` jar files using your platform classifier, to `-mac-source` and `-mac-javadoc` (or `win`, or `linux` based on your platform). Do this for the different JavaFX modules:

[image]

Back to NetBeans, check that now you have JavaDoc, or if you press Ctrl/CMD+Click you can access the source.

[image]

Note that this fix has to be done only once, the rest of your Maven projects should pick JavaDoc and Sources.

Comment: Thank you. I had it the other way around. I thought Netbeans would refuse to download the sources, but instead it is simply "to stupid" to ignore the classifier when searching for the matching source/doc archives. Is there an related Netbeans bug report?

Comment: There you go: [issue 1396](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1396?jql=project%20%3D%20NETBEANS%20AND%20text%20~%20javafx).

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll add this answer to the issue.

Comment: I don't mind. I would really like to avoid this workaround. ;-)