# Some of the JavaFX docs are missing (NetBeans 11)

Tags: javafx, javadoc, netbeans-11

Recently I've started to work with Maven JavaFX11 (openJFX11) and I noticed that there are many issues with javadoc in NetBeans. After some research I found that there is a bug with NetBeans that doesn't download the source+docs dependecies the right way (I mean it downloads it, but the next step to make it work is that you rename the source+docs files

- [issue & solution right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278159/javafx-11-in-netbeans-10-with-maven-has-no-sources-javadocs)

But after I did that I noticed another docs issue and I have not found any similar topic on this so i dont know if it's just me or somebody have/had the same problem

- When i type something like this:

`private Label label;
 label.[something...]`

- **It only shows some of the docs.**
- It describes object Label the right way
- **After I type the dot, it only tells me about like 1/5 of the docs.** Let me show you simple example.
  [image]
- And here is example of one that works
  [image]

I looked into the javafx docs (.jar) and opened the Note.html and there ARE as the same things as in the docs they have on their websites, including all the methods, etc.

So... Dont you know, where the problem might be? I'm using the openJFX 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have encountered a known issue. See these NetBeans Bug Reports:

- [NETBEANS-1396 Maven: Downloaded javadoc / sources not attached to artifact with classifier](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1396).
- [NETBEANS-2197 Missing code completion and Javadocs in maven projects with classifier](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2197).

Also see these OpenJFX issues:

- [How to add javadoc in Netbeans #44](https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/44)
- [Attached Javadoc does not follow Maven convention #6](https://github.com/openjfx/javadoc/issues/6)

The fix is being implemented through [a pull request for NetBeans 1396](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/1548).

[That fix is already included in NetBeans 11.3](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/milestone/4) which has a target release date of "*January 15, 2020*".

Comment: Is that a NetBeans 11 specific bug? What if I downgrade to NB10? Would the jdk11+javafx still work but without this doc bug?