# Javadoc not found, JavaFX. Can't Attatch JavaDoc

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, javadoc, java-13

[image]

I have tried for a while now, tried different things. But I cannot get JavaDocs to work for Netbeans 11.2, running Java 13.0.2

Everytime I try to see the Javadoc for JavaFX I get that message. Could someone help me with this?

[image]
It's not possible to attach a JavaDoc folder to it, and the "download" just gives a "no javadoc for javafx-graphics-13-win.jar available".

My platform manager looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ show JavaDocs tooltip on mouse over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615516/intellij-show-javadocs-tooltip-on-mouse-over)

Comment: @mrek No, I don't get any information from the JavaDocs for anything related to JavaFX. I can see JavaDocs to non javafx things.

Comment: no idea, just wondering about the name of the module jar: mine is javafx.graphics.jar (not javafx-graphics-13-win.jar)

Comment: [1] See NetBeans Bug Report 3296: [Attaching JavaFX Javadoc and Sources](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3296). [2] Please consider editing your question's title since it doesn't accurately reflect your actual problem.

Comment: Okay I changed the title hopefully that satisfy an accurate reflection to the problem. The bug report doesn't really help me as it's unresolved, but I will try to fiddle with it.@skomisa

Comment: @kleopatra hmm, did you install with with OpenJFX?

Comment: The workaround is renaming the javadoc jar and the source jar. Something like `javafx-graphics-13-win-javadoc.jar` and `javafx-graphics-13-win-source.jar`

Comment: @Sedrick yeah, but my files are allready name all that. The only thing is, I dont have the win-source file anywhere at the other files

Comment: You need to download the source jar.

Comment: All you have to do is follow the instructions of the duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278159/javafx-11-in-netbeans-10-with-maven-has-no-sources-javadocs

Comment: https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/44